# Page doesn't load with router mode: history on Apache

Tags: javascript, apache, .htaccess, vue.js, vue-router

I wanted to get rid of hash (#) from app's URL:

<s>`http://localhost/CoreUI-Vue/Vue_Starter/dist/#/dashboard`</s> `http://localhost/CoreUI/Vue_Starter/dist/dashboard`

so I've changed `mode` option in `vue-router` from `hash` to `history` in `router/index.js`:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
```

but afterwards, **when I recompiled the source code (`npm run build`) and opened the app (`http://localhost/CoreUI/Vue_Starter/dist/dashboard`), it loaded an empty page**:

```
<body class="app header-fixed sidebar-fixed aside-menu-fixed aside-menu-hidden">
<!---->
<script type="text/javascript" src="./static/js/manifest.7c717a1bcc0cc7dc29c1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./static/js/vendor.dfb9d96e757ce802aece.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./static/js/app.1cbf93c84add6c85b943.js"></script>
</body>
```

whereas router with `mode: 'hash'` (`http://localhost/CoreUI/Vue_Starter/dist/#/dashboard`) loads app without problems:

```
<body class="app header-fixed sidebar-fixed aside-menu-fixed aside-menu-hidden">
<div class="app">
    (...app content...)
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./static/js/manifest.a2cf3e09f095de958e46.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./static/js/vendor.dfb9d96e757ce802aece.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./static/js/app.72b651a6c3b2660db094.js"></script>
</body>
```

I realize that additional config has to be provided for web server for this to work, but it still didn't help me.

In Apache's config `httpd.conf` I ensured I have mod_rewrite turned on:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

I provided a support for history router in `.htaccess` (copied from [vue-router docs](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/history-mode.html)):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

`.htaccess` is located in same folder as project's `index.html`.

I'm working on empty [CoreUI-Vue](https://github.com/mrholek/CoreUI-Vue) template which uses most popular [Webpack/Vue boilerplate](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack), so there is rather nothing special about my code or config.

Comment: Don't have a server to try this on right now but your `RewriteBase` might need to be `/CoreUI/Vue_Starter/dist/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you use production build. I think you should add VirtualHost in Apache config to have paths like in production environment:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "c:\path_to_dist"

    ServerName servername.localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

And add to `/etc/hosts` (Linux) or `c:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` (Windows):

```
127.0.0.1 servername.localhost
```

I prefer this way because you can use every `.htaccess` configuration from any framework manual without additional editing and you don't have any path problems.

Of course, if you don't want this solution you can edit that `.htaccess` to something like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . CoreUI/Vue_Starter/dist/index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

I'm not sure if that works (didn't use Apache from years), but I'm sure you have to edit that last `RewriteRule` or `RewriteBase`.